# N+1 in javascript not working as intended

Tags: javascript, html

I got this img gallery from another question in Stack Overflow, and I added some buttons to be able to change the current img by `+1` and `-1`.

However it's not quite working, What am I doing wrong?

Here is a fiddle as well if you want to try it for yourself:

https://jsfiddle.net/k5r98foh/1/

```
<div class="container3 wrapper">
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="bb" style="background-image:url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-NREkKmTtXX0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAADg/w2IRnCo5AwQ/photo.jpg?sz=328);"></div>
    <!-- The above div is the problem -->
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyV3d.gif" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <!-- pass this to handler -->
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-NREkKmTtXX0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAADg/w2IRnCo5AwQ/photo.jpg?sz=328" onclick="currentSlide(this,1)" width="100%" alt="text">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <!-- pass this to handler -->
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyV3d.gif" width="100%" onclick="currentSlide(this, 2)" alt="text">
    </div>
  </div>
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>
</div>
```

-Javascript

```
var slideIndex = 1;
let wrappers = document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper");
wrappers.forEach(function(el) {
  showSlides(slideIndex, el);
});



// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(el, n) {
  // Get the wrapper element and pass it as a variable to showSlides
  let wrapper = el.closest(".wrapper");
  showSlides(slideIndex = n, wrapper);
}

function showSlides(n, wrapper) {
  var i;
  // find only the slides and dot that are decedents of current wrapper
  var slides = wrapper.querySelectorAll(".mySlides");
  var dots = wrapper.querySelectorAll(".demo");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }

  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }

  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace("active", "");
  }

  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

Comment: There are no elements with class `wrapper`. There is no global variable called `wrapper` but you're using it here: `wrapper.querySelectorAll(".mySlides")`

Comment: I added a wrapper:)

Comment: So, is it working as intended now?

Comment: No the buttons still doesnt work

Comment: (function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
})

Comment: There is quite some redundancy in your code. Your slides can be manged more easily if organise all your images in a JavaScript array/object structure and build everything from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `showSlides()` function call in `plusSlides()` is missing the wrapper context. Change it to:

```
function plusSlides(el,n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n, el.closest('.wrapper'));
}
```

and add the reference to the element itself (`this`) into the function call in your `<a>` tags:

```
<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(this,-1)">❮</a>
<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(this,1)">❯</a>
```

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
let wrappers = document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper");
wrappers.forEach(function(el) {
  showSlides(slideIndex, el);
});



// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(el,n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n,el.closest('.wrapper'));
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(el, n) {
  // Get the wrapper element and pass it as a variable to showSlides
  let wrapper = el.closest(".wrapper");
  showSlides(slideIndex = n, wrapper);
}

function showSlides(n, wrapper) {
  var i;
  // find only the slides and dot that are decedents of current wrapper
  var slides = wrapper.querySelectorAll(".mySlides");
  var dots = wrapper.querySelectorAll(".demo");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }

  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }

  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace("active", "");
  }

  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
.container3 {
position:absolute;
height:100px;
width:20%;
margin:auto;
right:0;
left:0;
}
.bb{
  height:100px;
    background: center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.row {
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
}
.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="container3 wrapper">
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="bb" style="background-image:url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-NREkKmTtXX0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAADg/w2IRnCo5AwQ/photo.jpg?sz=328);"></div>
    <!-- The above div is the problem -->
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyV3d.gif" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <!-- pass this to handler -->
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-NREkKmTtXX0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAADg/w2IRnCo5AwQ/photo.jpg?sz=328" onclick="currentSlide(this,1)" width="100%" alt="text">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <!-- pass this to handler -->
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyV3d.gif" width="100%" onclick="currentSlide(this, 2)" alt="text">
    </div>
  </div>
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(this,-1)">❮</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(this,1)">❯</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Works great, however I got multiple wrappers, how can I change this to work then?:) If you don't know its okey:)

Comment: I fixed the code so it will work with multiple wrappers. However, the code can be freed of a lot of redundancy and be made a lot cleaner. E. g. the click-event-handlers should be assigned using an `.addEventListener()`, preferably on `.wrapper`-level with if clauses or a case construct to deal with the different widgets.

Comment: okey, il take a look into addEventListender() :) . Did the change go through cause it looks pretty much the same to me tho?:)

Comment: Uuuuups, you were right, my changes weren't saved. Please look again now. ;-)

Comment: thanks alot for the example and the explantion, I tried with this,1 but the function was the flaw.